# sed(1): add a line at the end of a PHP array

Tags: php, sed

I have the following PHP file:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

I want to add a line in the $bundles variable at the end, considering the fact that last line might have and might not have a comma at the end.

The line I need to add is as follows:

```
new FOS\\UserBundle\\FOSUserBundle()
```

I wrote my version, but it doesn't work in cases if there is a comma in the last element of the $bundles array.

Slight modification is required, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
sed '/bundles.=.array/,/);/ { /[^(,;]$/ s//&,\n            new FOS\\UserBundle\\FOSUserBundle()/ }' app/AppKernel.php;
```

The end file should look like this:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(), //with comma or without

        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: the comma says there is a new element, so it makes no sense?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with sed? Whats wrong with a text editor?

Comment: I do it quite often so I thought I'd automate it. I'll make the insertion string a parameter later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes without saying that if the format of your file deviates too much this will fail, but for your case the following works with GNU sed:

*add_line.sed*

```
/bundles.=.array/ {     # When the right array is found
  : a
  N                     # Keep two lines in pattern space
  /);/bb                # Jump to b when end of array reached
  P                     # Print first line of pattern space
  s/[^\n]*\n//          # and delete it
  ba                    # Jump to a and repeat
  : b
  /,\n/! s#\n#,\n#      # Ensure comma ends the line before end of array
  s#\([ \t]*\)\([^\n]*\)\n#\1\2\n\1new FOS\\UserBundle\\FOSUserBundle()\n#
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -f add_line.sed app/AppKernel.php
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
sed '/bundles.=.array/ { :a; N; /);/bb; P; s/[^\n]*\n//; ba; :b; /,\n/! s#\n#,\n#; s#\([ \t]*\)\([^\n]*\)\n#\1\2\n\1new FOS\\UserBundle\\FOSUserBundle()\n#; }' app/AppKernel.php
```

Excerpt of output:

```
...
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()
    );

...
```